# Angular - Getting list of files from local directory

Tags: angular

I am trying to read a list of files from a local directory using Angular 5-.

However i get the following error:

> TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function

My .ts file is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-review',
  templateUrl: './review.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review.component.css']
})
export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readdir('./assets', function (err, files) {
      // "files" is an Array with files names
            console.log(files);

  });
  }

}
```

Note have done npm install fs --save.

Also please help me finding datemodified info of the files.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser? If so, that's not possible - you can only read the file system in node, on the server.

Comment: Am trying to do this on browser....Any thoughts how could I achieve that?

Comment: You can't - it's not possible, as I said. The browser cannot read the filesystem, except for uploading files - and you can't read the file contents in that case. That would be a huge security risk if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871259/angular4-read-local-files/44871842#44871842