# How to read filenames from internal folder structure Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v7

I have a requirement something like I have languages json file such as 
da-DA.json de-DE.json in my assets folder inside i18n directory in which the language mapping is written.
Now I want a dropdown where I can have my users select these languages.
But I'm facing challenge to map it to my component. I saw these answers which states it is not possible to do so in the following links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871259/angular4-read-local-files/44871842#44871842)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833475/angular-getting-list-of-files-from-local-directory)

So I wanted to know which is the right way to achieve something like this.

Comment: You need to import `json` data in your component and display it in `select` dropdown using `ngFor`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876138/11719787) to import json file in component/ts

Comment: I just want filenames from that i18n directory in my assets folder not the content from the json files

Comment: You can't access **files** or **file names** (Basically a file system) using front end frame-work or javascript. The above links you provided already answered for this question.

Comment: I have a project where we do that exactly. We use this library https://github.com/ngx-translate/core It's worth checking it out.